# Selector, окрашивающий кнопку

Tags: android, xml

Привет!

Есть `ImageButton`, в который устанавливаю иконку (`android:src`). Как можно сделать `selector`, чтобы при нажатии менялся цвет **иконки**, а не фона (что-то вроде `ColorFilter`)?

Я не хочу:

1. Создавать `selector` и делать уже готовые окрашенные иконки, потому что у меня их около 200 штук (200 штук в обычном состоянии + 200 в наведённом состоянии, 200 штук в нажатом состоянии, 200 `selector`'ов - итого уже минимум 800 файлов).
2. Делать свой кастомный `ImageButton`.
3. Использовать библиотеки.

Если быть короче, то как сделать "tint" иконки на кнопке в её `selector`, используя только xml (хотелось бы создать один `selector` для всех иконок сразу, в котором указываются цвета для окрашивания)? Использую API 14, так что всякие новомодные штучки врядли сработают.

Comment: А стандартный для web'а вариант со спрайтом не подходит?

Comment: И чего вы все к этому xml привязались. Знаете ведь, что он там ущербный. Android-support-v4 v22.1.0 с его DrawableCompat и немного глючной, но зато из коробки, реализацией android:tint внешней библиотекой можно не считать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ запоздалый, но всё же лучше поздно, чем никогда.

Итак, как отмечали пользователи, чистым xml мне выполнить поставленную задачу не удалось. Однако я всё равно добился своего. Итак, мне нужно было сделать ImageButton, окрашивающую свою иконку при изменении состояния кнопки.

**Открываем файл `/res/values/colors.xml` и добавляем строки** (в моём случае цвета окрашивания зелёного оттенка)

```
<!-- Цвет в обычном состоянии -->
<color name="tint_idle">#99CC00</color>
<!-- Цвет в сфокусированном состоянии -->
<color name="tint_focused">#8BC34A</color>
<!-- Цвет в выбранном состоянии -->
<color name="tint_selected">#8BC34A</color>
<!-- Цвет в нажатом состоянии -->
<color name="tint_pressed">#669900</color>
```

**Открываем файл `/res/values/attrs.xml` и добавляем строки**

```
<!-- Будет указываться в разметке -->
<declare-styleable name="TintableImageView">
    <attr name="tintColors" format="color|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
<!-- Будет указываться в теме -->
<declare-styleable name="TintableImageViewStyle">
    <attr name="tintableImageButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**Создаём папку `/res/color` и файл `tib_colors` в ней**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/tint_focused" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/tint_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/tint_pressed" />
    <item android:color="@color/tint_idle" />
 </selector>
```

**Если в приложении задана пользовательская тема, то открываем `styles.xml` или `themes.xml` (у вас может быть по-разному)...**

```
<!-- ...добавляем ещё один xmlns в корневой элемент -->
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
<!-- ...добавляем строку в используемую тему -->
 <item name="tintableImageButtonStyle">@style/Widget_TintableImageButton</item>
<!-- ...и добавляем стиль TintableImageButton -->
<style name="Widget_TintableImageButton" >
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="tintColors">@color/tib_colors</item>
</style>
```

**Если в приложении нет темы, то придётся дописывать `app:tintColors` к каждой нужной кнопке и добавлять `xmlns` в разметку**

**Создаём класс `TintableImageButton` и наследуем его от `ImageButton`**

```
 public class TintableImageButton extends ImageButton
 {
     private ColorStateList mTintList;
    private TypedArray mTypedArray;

    public TintableImageButton(Context mContext, AttributeSet mAttrSet)
    {
        this(mContext, mAttrSet, R.attr.tintableImageButtonStyle);
    } 

    public TintableImageButton(Context mContext, AttributeSet mAttrSet, int mDefaultStyle)
    {
        super(mContext, mAttrSet, mDefaultStyle);
        initialize(mContext, mAttrSet, mDefaultStyle);
    }

    private void initialize(Context mContext, AttributeSet mAttrSet, int mDefaultStyle)
    {
        mTypedArray = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(mAttrSet, R.styleable.TintableImageView, mDefaultStyle, 0);
        mTintList = mTypedArray.getColorStateList(R.styleable.TintableImageView_tintColors);
        mTypedArray.recycle();
    }

     @Override
     protected void drawableStateChanged()
     {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        if (mTintList != null && mTintList.isStateful())
        {
            int mNewColor = mTintList.getColorForState(getDrawableState(), 0);
            setColorFilter(mNewColor);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Использование в проекте**

```
 <путь.к.классу.TintableImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="путь к иконке"
    app:tintColors="@color/tib_colors (убрерите эту строку, если используется тема)" />
```

**Результат**

[image: Изображение]

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что для озвученных условий (API 14, только средствами xml, без расширения класса `ImageButton` и библиотек) нет корректного решения.

<strike>Только начиная с API 21 в xml-атрибуты было введено свойство `android:tint` (и соответствующие методы для виджетов).</strike>

Можно придумать какой то адский костыль вроде заранее подготовленного изображения:

1. Само изображение имеет некоторую прозрачность.
2. Фон изображения не прозрачный.
3. Далее мы изменяем цвет фона с помощью селектора и за счет полупрозрачности картинки изменяется ее цвет.

Ничего более подходящего в голову не приходит, остальные варианты предполагают либо расширение класса `ImageButton`, либо манипуляции с изображением из кода.

Так же в библиотеке `AppCompat` есть виджет `AppCompatButton`, который реализует [TintableBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html), то есть вы могли бы использовать простую кнопку как `ImageButton`, установив свое изображение в качестве фона и не задавая текст кнопки, затем управлять смешением цветов этого фона, но и использование библиотек вам почему то претит.

Со своей стороны не могу понять, чем вызвано ограничение на кастомный виджет, реализующий необходимую функциональность - это было бы самым эффективным решением вашей задачи.

Comment: Вот это вот ограничение на extends ImageView :) меня тоже ввело в ступор :)

Answer (score 1):

В android-support-v4 v22.1.0 есть DrawableCompat, там можно установить tint. Кроме того, с ним android:tint на ImageView и ImageButton должен работать из коробки на всех версиях android (правда, у меня возникли проблемы на 4.1).
В любомй случае, кастомный ImageButton вышел бы в десяток строк кода. Не понимаю, почему вы его избегаете.

Comment: `android:tint` работает с `ImageButton` и `ImageView` с API 1 как бы, без всяких библиотек поддержки .. а вот в селектор это прописать - тут уже проблема

Answer (score 0):

В общем у меня получилось :) но это такой изврат :)))

```
    int widthBmp=50;
    int heightBmp=50;

    Drawable drawable1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_circle_white);
    drawable1.setBounds(0, 0, widthBmp, heightBmp);

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthBmp, heightBmp, conf);
    Canvas cc = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable1.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    drawable1.draw(cc);             
    BitmapDrawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);              

    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},drawable2);
    states.addState(new int[] {},drawable1);

    ImageView imageView1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Сначала пробовал просто использовать drawable2,скопировав drawable1 и задать ему colorFilter, но Увы, при передаче drawable в StateListDrawable данные по colorFilter теряются, поэтому Пришлось отрисовать первый с colorFilter на canvas, и создать BitmapDrawable и уже его передать в StateList как state_pressed. Тут надо серьезно думать над оптимизацией и очисткой bitmap, особенное если 200 иконок - потому что создание 200 bitmap это почти гарантированный out_of_memory.+ Размеры - над ними думай сам, если размеры (widthBmp,heightBmp) изначально не задать , то drawable не нарисуются.

Comment: Можно использовать кастомный drawable еще, будет гораздо проще и оптимальнее. Например можно тупо StateListDrawable extends И если state_pressed - применять colorFilter - не надо Bitmap создавать.